# Delphi, MSXML2.XMLHTTP, PHP and Win-1250 charset encoding

Tags: php, xml, delphi, unicode, non-ascii-characters

Hoi!

I trying to make a webservice in Windows.

The client is Delphi 6, with MSXML2.XMLHTTP call, and other side is PHP.

First I tested: can I receive hungarian XML?

The PHP source was UTF-8 encoded file (PSPAD).

```
$s = 'alma árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép beta';
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$m = $doc->createElement('package');
$doc->appendChild($m);
$n = $doc->createElement('Msg');
$m->appendChild($n);
$n->nodeValue = $s;
$xs = $doc->saveXML();
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo($xs);
```

This package I fully got in Delphi side, the accents are ok.

So then I tried to inject data from xml (post xml to php with accents).

```
global $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
$xmlstr = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$msg = $xml->msg;
#$msg = 'ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP';
```

Ok, I got the "msg" field, but nevertheless I trying to convert it, everytime I got some convert notice, and the result is not same as when I set the variable directly...

The debug is:

```
echo(utfCharToNumber($sinput).'<br>');
echo(utfCharToNumber($sdefined).'<br>');

Input:   195[   ]8286195141908419717682197[   ]328419
Defined: 195[129]8286195141908419717682197[144]328419
Input:   5156751951508270195154821951477119513780<br>
Defined: 5156751951508270195154821951477119513780<br>
```

As you see that two holes I have in the variable when I converted the input from MSXML2.

I really don't understand this.

I cannot reproduce same XML output from get the data from input XML as when I set directly in PHP code...

Why?

Thanks for your every help, idea, link, document, little example!

dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem was the Delphi code.

Priorly I used AnsiToUTF8 to encode the XML text. 
But the COM object is uses UTF16 as I think.

The working code is this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    mhttp : variant;
    ws : WideString;
    tosend : OleVariant;
    xml : TXMLDocument;
    n : IXMLNode;
begin
    mhttp := CreateOleObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');
    mhttp.Open('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1/test_xmlgen.php', False);

    xml := CreateANewDocument(Self, '', 'a');
    n := xml.DocumentElement.AddChild('msg');
    n.NodeValue := 'ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP';
    xml.SaveToXML(ws);
    tosend := ws;

    mhttp.send(tosend);
    Memo1.Lines.Text :=
        IntToStr(mhttp.Status) + #13 +
        mhttp.responseText + #13;
end;
```

This can resend the XML I sent - with good accents.

Thanks for your help:
  dd

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't included Delphi source, I suspect you're posting data straight from a string as content body of the request, which is encoded in the current ANSI encoding by default in Delphi 6. I advise you either use `Utf8Encode` on the string before you add this as the request's body data, or add a 'Content-encoding' request header with the name of the ANSI encoding (if I remember correctly [GetLocaleInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) could give you this).